# Cygwin Compiler: Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, cygwin

When I try to compile a random project in Code:Blocks, the Cygwin Compiler throws an undefined reference error about own library files:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libcygwin.a(_cygwin_crt0_common.o):_cygwin_crt0_common.cc:(.data+0x0):
undefined reference to `___real__Znwj'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../libcygwin.a(_cygwin_crt0_common.o):_cygwin_crt0_common.cc:(.data+0x8):
undefined reference to `___real__ZdlPv'
```

I am linking the netlink library as well as the WS2_32.lib

Is that a compiler issue?

Comment: In case it's some kind of clue, `__Znwj` is the symbol for the global `operator new(unsigned int)` and `__ZdlPv` is for the global `operator delete(void*)`. I don't know what the `___real` prefix indicates.  I'd guess that you just need to link in the C++ library, which should be done automatically if the `g++` command is being invoked for the link step. Do you have any idea what command code::blocks is using to link the program?

Comment: @MichaelBurr is right. the __Znwj is name mangling that happens during the compilation process.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Code::blocks is running this command: _g++-3.exe -LC:/Users/Public/Documents/PROJEKTE/chatserver/ -LD:/CodeBlocks/include -LC:/Users/Public/Documents/PROJEKTE/chatserver/  -o ChatServer.exe .objs/main.o    -lnetlink /cygdrive/c/Users/Public/Documents/PROJEKTE/chatserver/WS2_32.Lib -lnetlink C:/Users/Public/Documents/PROJEKTE/chatserver/WS2_32.Lib_

Answer (score 0):

Other hint, it comes from `_cygwin_crt0_common.cc`. So there is obviously central something missing. You are using Cygwin version of gcc, right? Have your tried `-lcygwin`? You could also try `-mno-cygwin`.

My advice is normally to use vanilla MinGW, creates clean windows binaries (at the loss of POSIX features)..

Comment: `-mno-cygwin` has been removed/deprecated in MinGW*/Cygwin GCC.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. But it was "only" year ago... And I try to avoid cygwin like hell.

Comment: I believe MinGW* GCC 4.6 produces an error when you pass `-mno-cygwin` to it, that's more than a year ago. And the reason Python distutils is not usable as is on that platform.